# Sending SMS using ASP.NET (C#) through HTTP

Tags: c#, asp.net

Have you tried OZEKI NG SMS Gateway? Now I'm testing how to send SMS using ASP.NET (C#) through HTTP by OZEKI NG SMS Gateway free trial service but I got an error and I don't know how to configure it.

Comment: Have you tried that example project? Could you post the error that you're receiving?

Comment: yes i already try with this example project. before i add <pages validateRequest="false"></pages> and <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/> to web.config file it show error: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$MainContent$textboxError="<Responses><Response...").

Comment: after i added this <pages validateRequest="false"></pages> and <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/> to web.config file i got more error like this: <Responses><Response0><Action>sendMessage</Action><Data><AcceptReport><StatusCode>0</StatusCode><StatusText>Message accepted for delivery</StatusText><MessageID>89c8011c-e291-44c3-ac72-cd35c76cb29d</MessageID><Recipient>+85568922903</Recipient></AcceptReport></Data></Response0></Responses>.

Comment: After i added string result = Regex.Replace(responseString, @"<[^>]*>", string.Empty); to my aspx.cs file and now i got this error : sendMessage0Message accepted for delivery71d58932-8dea-4e80-af66-24a3e9ac011c+85568922903. What is my problem?

Comment: **Message accepted for delivery**. It is working!

Comment: you tried it? what do you changed from source codes?

Comment: I'm just reading your comment. Look at the response you got, it says **Message accepted for delivery**. It's working, but you should remind that the message is not sent in real time to the telephony carrier

Comment: yes i think it is working but i don't see message in my phone number. why?

Comment: and the successfully should show similar this message Message accepted for delivery
Message ID: IEUHSHIL
Recipient: +441234567 just different phone number and Message ID  http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=239&sms_api=Run_the_example_code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after all these comments, let's try to explain what's happening: **it is working**. You're sending a HTTP request and you're getting a response that says it.

Take a look here (you posted it at a comment!):

```
<Responses>
    <Response0>
        <Action>sendMessage</Action>
        <Data>
            <AcceptReport>
                <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
                <StatusText>Message accepted for delivery</StatusText>
                <MessageID>89c8011c-e291-44c3-ac72-cd35c76cb29d</MessageID>
                <Recipient>+85568922903</Recipient>
            </AcceptReport>
        </Data>
    </Response0>
</Responses>
```

All you need is to work with this XML data. Take a look here at SO, there's lot of questions about it.

Comment: so you mean that i need to create xml data file? sorry what is SO? how can i go to take a look?

Comment: SO is **S** tack **O** verflow =) Do a little search here and at Google. You need to translate that XML to an object so you can retrieve the meaningful data, such as `MessageID` and `Recipient`.

Comment: ok i will search. do you tried send SMS using ASP.NET (C#) through HTTP bye OZEKI NG SMS Gateway example project yet?

Comment: Yes, and I got the same result as you but the message haven't arrive yet. Don't forget to vote the answer and mark as result =)

Comment: yes and don't forget to give me right answer if you already configured it

Comment: I'm sorry but what answer else do you need? The service is working and you just need to process that return, everything is ok!

Comment: ok i will do first and let you know later

Comment: Ok, let me know if anything goes wrong

Comment: after some search i see some answer but it's not correct answer. so i really don't know how to  translate that XML to an object in this example project. can you let me know?